# Single Bind Statement For Entire Page

Tags: javascript, data-binding, rivets.js

Using RivetsJS is there any reason (performance wise) why it would be a bad idea to bind an entire presentation model to the `<body>` tag as opposed to bind individual objects to individual elements?

Something like this:

```
Model = {}
rivets.bind($('body').get(), {model: Model})

$.ajax({...success: function(response){Model.selectedUser = response}})
```

Just seems like it would make life easier and keep the presentation model bound to the view at all times.